# setTimeout() not working

Tags: javascript

I want to count up the number of below textbox each 1 second.
 I tried it like below.but this not work...I don't know where I did mistake.
 and also i want to stop that count after the text box value reach 10.
 Please give me the solution any one...thanks

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
var fun = function()
{

var count = $("#target :text").val();

$("#target :text").val(count++);

setTimeout(fun, 1000);

}

fun();
</script>

<div id="target">
<input type="text" value="0">
</div>
```

Comment: You have setup fun as a variable so the fun() you use to start the process is not being run

Comment: @TobyOsborne that doesn't matter - calling `fun()` will still work. Try it - type `var fun = function() { alert("hi"); }` into your console, then call `fun()`.

Comment: am also think fun() is not a problem...i check it out...

Comment: wow ur right thought you had to return a value if it was set as a variable. clearly not learn something new everyday. anyway Satpal's answer seems to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `++count` instead of `count++`, Problem with you code is that you are using post increment.

```
$("#target :text").val(++count);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/F3yk7/)

Additionally, I would recommend you to use [document-ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) handler.

### EDIT

**Example with Pre increment**

```
var count  = 0; //Suppose
$("#target :text").val(++count);
```

equivalent to

```
var count  = 0; 
count = count + 1;
$("#target :text").val(count); //Will set value as 1
```

---

**Example with POST increment**

```
var count  = 0; //Suppose
$("#target :text").val(count++);
```

equivalent to

```
var count  = 0; 
$("#target :text").val(count); //Will set value as 0
count = count + 1;
```

Comment: @kalyan, I have given example that will explain. Still you have problem ping me

Comment: Wow very cleared...i think no one can not give the more understandable answer compare then this...thanks Satpal.

Comment: This answer does not take into account that a setTimeout or setInterval isn't a realtime operation. Your time will be off. Do not use a counter.  

Use a Date object to calculate elapsed time, show the # of seconds elapsed, and then you can use a setInterval to update the view.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that, `val()` gives you a **string**.

```
var fun = function() {
    var el = $("#target :text");
    var count = parseInt(el.val(), 10);
    el.val(count+1);
    setTimeout(fun, 1000); 
}

fun();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this, actually counting seconds instead of counter:

```
var t = new Date(), a = setInterval(function() {
    $("#target>").filter(':input').val(function() {
        if ((c = (Date.now() - t.getTime()) / 1000) >= 10)
            clearInterval(a);

        return Math.round(c);
    });
}, 1000);
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/S74DR/9/).

**EDIT:**

Just because I love Coffeescript:

```
t = new Date()

a = setInterval ->
    $('#target>').filter(':input').val ->
        clearInterval a if (c = (Date.now() - t.getTime()) / 1000) >= 10

        Math.round c
, 1000
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of the answers are plain wrong and confusing and don't get what's really wrong with this.
Your way of setting up the interval loop is completely correct.

What you missed is that `count++` will return `count` and then increase it.
So you always set the count to `0`. You first need to increase `count` and then set it.
You could use `++count` as Satpal proposed.

I think it's cleaner to create a temporary variable for it like `var updatedTime = count + 1;` and then set it to `updatedTime`. That way it's much clearer and way more difficult to be bitten by a bug such as yours. Functionality wise, both approaches are the same though.

Answer (score 1):

[Keep it simple](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/NLR66/):

```
function fun (){
 $("#target :input").val(function(){return +this.value + 1;});
 setTimeout(fun, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/39qVC/

```
var fun = function ()
    {
        var count = $("#target :text").val();
        if(count >= 10) {
            clearTimeout(loop);
        }
        else
        {
            $("#target :text").val(parseInt(count, 10) + 1);
        }
    }

    var loop;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var count = $("#target :text").val();
        loop = setInterval(fun , 1000);
    });
```

Comment: Not quite there. Always use parseInt(x, 10) if using base 10 numbers, otherwise guess what happens with parseInt('08')?

Answer (score 0):

None of these answers take into account that a setTimeout or setInterval isn't a realtime operation. Your time will be off. Do not use a counter.

Use a Date object to calculate elapsed time, show the # of seconds elapsed, and then you can use a setInterval to update the view.

Answer (score -1):

Try below code its work..

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 <script>
 function fun()
 {
   var count = $("#target :text").val();
   count= parseInt(count) +1;// We have to parse value in to the int or other datatype.
   $("#target :text").val(count);
 }
   setInterval('fun()', 100);
</script>
<div id="target">
<input type="text" value="0">
</div>
```

We need to parse the count value because it is in the string format.

Comment: This is really bad. You should never pass strings to `setInterval` to have them `eval`'d. Always pass references to functions.